# How Can I Hide Few Object on JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript

So, i have this data array like this

```
    "books" : [
          {
              "id": 1
              "name":"History"
          },
          {
              "id": 2
              "name":"Physics"
          }
    ]
```

and the result that I want to show is like this(without deleting it),

```
    "books" : [
          {
              "name":"History"
          },
          {
              "name":"Physics"
          }
    ]
```

I'm so confused here, thank you for helping.

Comment: Hi There. You should try atleast some approach first. What have you researched so far ? Where are you stuck exactly ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing like `hiding` or `showing` property in JS.

If it is an array then you can filter the objects and get the filtered ones.

If it is an object then you can get the specific property from the object.

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and get the property from the object(in this case is `name`).

```js
const obj = {
  books: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "History",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Physics",
    },
  ],
};

const result = obj.books.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { name } = curr;
  acc["books"] ? acc["books"].push({ name }) : (acc["books"] = [{ name }]);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```